# What is the 'this' reference here?

Tags: javascript, this

I am reading [this chapter in You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) .

```
function baz() {
    // call-stack is: `baz`
    // so, our call-site is in the global scope
    console.log("baz");
    bar(); // <-- call-site for `bar`
}


function bar() {
    // call-stack is: `baz` -> `bar`
    // so, our call-site is in `baz`
    console.log("bar");
    foo(); // <-- call-site for `foo`
}

function foo() {
    // call-stack is: `baz` -> `bar` -> `foo`
    // so, our call-site is in `bar`
    console.log("foo");
    console.log(this);
}

baz(); // <-- call-site for `baz`
```

I was expecting the `console.log(this)` in function `foo` to print `bar`, since `bar` is the call site, but instead it seems to be `window`.

How is the `this` reference `window` instead of `bar` inside the function *foo* ?

Comment: __window__..... As `this` belongs to `owner` of the `method` being called!(If `.bind/.call/.apply` are not considered!)

Comment: `this` isn't determined by the location of the call, just by the manner (how it was called). In all 3 cases, the functions are called simply as local functions (vs. as methods, etc.) – `fn()` – so `this` will be the default value, either the global object (`window` in browsers) or `undefined` (strict mode). This is discussed a few paragraphs after the snippet: [Default Binding](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#default-binding).

Comment: this SO question will help you out :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: @RayonDabre—there is no such thing as "owner", you might mean [*base* value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reference-specification-type). *foo* is called without a base value or its *this*, so when resolving its *this* value, *getBase* returns *undefined* and its *this* defaults to the global (window in a browser) object, or remains undefined in strict mode.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski—except in arrow functions of course. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, Agreed! :(  _"A function's this is set by how it's called"_ does sound perfect :)

Comment: @RayonDabre—well, that was true until *bind* (ES5) and arrow functions (ECMAScript 2015) were added to the language. ECMAScript 2017 may introduce more change (or not). ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained wonderfully by Kyle Simpson, the value of `this` depends on only 4 conditions depending on the call site:

```
var obj = {
  foo: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

function foo() { console.log(this); }
```

**1. Call using object(Implicit binding)**

> obj.foo();

In this case, `foo` is called using `obj` (always notice the object before the dot operator). Hence `this` refers to `obj` inside `foo`.

**2. 'call' or 'apply' (Explicit binding)**

> foo.call(obj);

Here, `this` inside the function `foo` refers to `obj` since it has been binded explicitly.

**3. Call using new (new keyword)**

> obj = new foo();

Inside foo, `this` now refers to the newly created object.

**4. Global object (Default Binding)**

> foo();

Here, `foo` is called directly. Hence it defaults to `window`. (This is your case!)

As you can see, in your case, `foo` is called directly(case 4). Hence `this` refers to the `window` object. Just remember these 4 cases and you will be good!

Answer (score 0):

'this' refers to the object that is calling the function, not the calling function. Are you running this code from a browser (i.e. from a web page)? If so, then 'this' is the window that the code is running in.

Comment: *'this' refers to the object that is calling the function*. Only sometimes. A function's *this* is set by how it's called—with a base (i.e. as a method), without a base (as in the OP), with *call* or *apply*. The exceptions are the use of *bind* and lexically in an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that 'bar' is the call site but you have to see which of the [4 rules](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#nothing-but-rules) apply to the call-site. In this case, there is no `new` binding. Similarly we do not see either hard, explicit or implicit binding since the `foo()` is not executed as `obj.foo()`. Thus it is a clear case of default binding hence `this` points to the global object i.e. `window`